# Use UIView.animateWithDuration inside protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

How can I use UIView.animateWithDuration inside Swift protocol? When I try to use it I always get:

> Ambiguous reference to member
>   'animateWithDuration(_:delay:options:animations:completion:)'

How I can get reference to UIView (`animateWithDuration` is static method as I understand)?

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can not provide any implementation inside protocol declaration itself, you should reference to `UIView` class inside default implementation. I hope one of this three template cases is what you need:

```
import UIKit

protocol SomeProtocol {
    static func animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, delay: NSTimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: () -> Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
    func animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, delay: NSTimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: () -> Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
    func someCustomFuncForAnimate()
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    static func animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, delay: NSTimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: () -> Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: animations, completion: completion)
    }
    func animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, delay: NSTimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: () -> Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: animations, completion: completion)
    }
    func someCustomFuncForAnimate() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 1, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {/*...*/}, completion: nil)
    }
}
```